# Cannot paste marked Java code in vscode with Java extension

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am using vscode for Java with the Java extensions. When I select a method, copy it via ctrl+c and just paste it with ctrl+v without moving the cursor a layover menu appears but nothing happens:

[image: screenshot of code that shows the layover menu]

What I expect it to do, like it always did and still does with Go and other languages is to replace the code with itself and place my cursor at the end.
Is there a way to disable this?

Comment: 1) what do you mean by "mark"? "select"? 2) how do you paste it without first copying it? your procedure does not mention copying. 3) why do you even want the cursor to move to the end? what good does this do you?

Comment: @starball my bad. I meant select, I am not a native English speaker. I added some additional information. I Select the code (as you can see in the screenshot), copy it with ctrl+c and just paste it without any other action before with ctrl+v.

Comment: please answer my question #3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature called [***Paste as***](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_79#_paste-as) was updated in May 2023.

You can disable this feature by unchecking it in the **Settings** panel or adding the following to ***settings.json***.

[image]

```json
    "editor.pasteAs.enabled": false,
```

Comment: Thank you! I missed that feature, I was searching for "format" instead. It works.

Comment: Glad you solved the problem. Can you share your solution? What features did you turn off after searching?

Comment: I disabled the "paste as" option your screenshot shows. I tried to find if there was a way to disable paste as for the Java Extension but I was unable to find an option.